# memory empty but swap full?

Tags: ram, swap, memory-usage

I'm on Ubuntu mate 21.04 with swappiness set to default 60. Why is the system predominantly using the swap if there is ~55 GB of empty memory? The swap file is on nvme drive but memory is  still faster so why with the default swappiness it is not being used more?

[image]

Comment: It just means that whatever process whose memory was pushed into swap is just not active for it to be pulled back into RAM. If it were, it would be.

Comment: With so much memory, you really don't need swap. Disable swap and use zram instead.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi My personal opinion is that **every** machine needs swap, no matter how much RAM. I recommend increasing the /swapfile from 2G to 4G, and setting vm.swappiness=10.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, a lot of swap is used despite low memory use and plenty of free memory. The current status depends on the history of use, though. If earlier in the session, memory was heavily used, unused pages would be swapped to disk. These pages will not be removed from swap, unless they are needed again. If not needed, they just will remain in swap even if a lot of free memory has become available again.

Comment: It is the other way around. That's why I'm asking because it is surprising to me. There is 7.1 GiB used and 55.5 GiB free. Yet instead of utilizing more of the memory the system is filling up the swap.

Comment: Right, I see. Thank you for correcting. That could be a result of use "history": swapped memory will not be released even if memory is being freed by other processes. To have the whole picture, you should actually follow how memory use and swap use evolve as you do particular things on the computer - I changed the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Historically, a 2G /swapfile has never been enough.

Let's increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G, and change your vm.swappiness value...

**/swapfile**

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 64G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**vm.swappiness**

Because you have so much RAM, set your vm.swappiness=10. This will reduce swapping on your configuration. It sounds like you know how to do this (edit /etc/sysctl.conf), but if not, please ask for further instructions.